# Why is this limit not indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac{-\varepsilon}{\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{x-\varepsilon}{x-\varepsilon-1}} \neq \frac{0}{0} $$

Since $\varepsilon \to 0$, I see the denominator also going to $0$. However, running this through Wolfram returns a finite limit. Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to 0} {\sin(x)\over x}$? Is it indeterminate?

Answer (score 2):

It’s just a bit of algebra:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{-\epsilon}{\frac{x}{x-1}-\frac{x-\epsilon}{x-\epsilon-1}}&=\frac{-\epsilon}{\frac{x(x-\epsilon-1)-(x-1)(x-\epsilon)}{(x-1)(x-\epsilon-1)}}\\
&=\frac{-\epsilon(x-1)(x-\epsilon-1)}{-\epsilon}\\
&=(x-1)(x-\epsilon-1)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had worked out the algebra and gotten that result as well. What is the fault in my mathematics where I jump to 0/0?

Comment: @clocktower: The original expression does indeed have a numerator and denominator that both tend to $0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$, but $\frac00$ is an indeterminate form: it tells you nothing about the actual limit, which may be anything or simply fail to exist. That means that one must look for some other approach to evaluating it. Here, simplifying the fraction works.